# What is the difference between the location of *: *variable vs variable*

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

I am currently using the Decawave DWM1000 and found the sample library online (https://github.com/thotro/arduino-dw1000).
We intend to manipulate the library and code functions for our own purposes. However the library may not be complete and there are several syntaxes used which I dont understand.

1) What does it mean when * is added at the back of a variable ( eg. DW1000Device*)
cant seem to find answers online. Usually only see * used at the front.

2) How do you comprehend void withn a void in a function 
   Also, How do you use (function1)(function2) 
(see the complex chunk of code below)

QNS1  //what does it mean when * is used at the front and back 
        eg. (* _handleBlinkDevice)(DW1000Device*)

```
static void (* _handleNewRange)(void);
static void (* _handleBlinkDevice)(DW1000Device*);
static void (* _handleNewDevice)(DW1000Device*);
static void (* _handleInactiveDevice)(DW1000Device*);
```

QNS2 // in function attachBlinkDevice, there is void inside, and why is there another 2 brackets (* handleBlinkDevice)(DW1000Device*) inside too?

```
static void attachBlinkDevice(void (* handleBlinkDevice)(DW1000Device*)) { _handleBlinkDevice = handleBlinkDevice; };
```

Comment: *"What does it mean when * is added at the back of a variable"* Those are function pointers. Their syntax is: `<return_type> (*<pointer_name>) (function_arguments);`

Comment: https://parrt.cs.usfca.edu/doc/how-to-read-C-declarations.html

Answer (score 3):

> 1) What does it mean when * is added at the back of a variable ( eg. DW1000Device*) cant seem to find answers online. Usually only see * used at the front.
>
> static void (* _handleBlinkDevice)(DW1000Device*);

*DW1000Device* is not a variable name but a type name

`_handleBlinkDevice` is a variable whose type is a function returning nothing (*void*) and getting in parameter a pointer to a *DW1000Device*

> 2) How do you comprehend void withn a void in a function Also, How do you use (function1)(function2) (see the complex chunk of code below)
>
> static void (* _handleNewRange)(void);

`_handleNewRange` is a variable whose type is a function returning nothing (*void*) and getting no argument

Answer (score 0):

This notation is declaring a function pointer, `void` is its return type `(* pointer_name)` is pointer name, and `(Type*)` is parameter list and to this specific case, the parameter is a pointer to `DW1000Device`